# how to localizing resources with the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

Hi there I am currently working though an exercise in the "iPhone Programing - The big nerd ranch guide" where they are describing how to add localization to your application.

However I have run into a small bump in the road, they are describing how to access the Get info from the contextual menu by right clicking the xib file in the file browser on the left of the screen.. I guess they are explaing how this is done with xcode 3.XXX but I am using xcode 4.XXX and am woundering if anyone can help me find this menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the information & tools contained in the Xcode 3.0 "Get Info" inspector are in now the "Utilities" panel view on the right side of Xcode 4.0.

Comment: Thankyou.. looked for it for about an hour.. lol pain in my ass.